# Ruby Mechanize web scraper library returns file instead of page

Tags: ruby, object, mechanize, scraper

I have recently been using the Mechanize gem in ruby to write a scraper. Unfortunately, the URL that I am attempting to scrape returns a `Mechanize::File` object instead of a `Mechanize::Page` object upon a `GET` request.

I can't figure out why. Every other URL I have tried has returned a `Mechanize::Page` object.

Is there some way to force Mechanize to return a `Page` object?

Comment: Give the two examples of pages which give the different results

Comment: This could be something the target server is doing based upon the User-Agent or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what's going on.

When you download a 'normal' web page, its header will have a field that says something like `Content-Type text/html`.  When Mechanize sees this, it knows to interpret the page content as HTML and parses it into a Mechanize::Page object, complete with links and forms and whatnot.

But if you've ever clicked on a link that says "download CSV data" or "download PDF" or, in short, anything that's not HTML, you're receiving a page that does not have a `Content-Type` of `text/html`.  Since Mechanize cannot parse non-html into a Mechanize::Page object, it will package up the content into a Mechanize::File object.

What you do with the Mechanize::File object depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  For example, if you know that the page you visited was CSV data rather than HTML, you can extract the CSV data like this:

```
page = web_agent.get(some_url_that_references_csv_data)
parsed_csv = CSV.parse(page.body)
```

If you want to be fancy, you can write your own parsers that allow Mechanize to handle non-HTML formats.  See [the Mechanize docs on PluggableParser](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/PluggableParser.html) if you want to go that route.  But you can accomplish plenty by working directly with the Mechanize::File object.

### addendum in response to @user741072's comment

If on the other hand, if the page *is* HTML and somebody neglected to set `content-type` to HTML, you can write a method that swaps in the html parser for the default parser just long enough to parse the page.  This will force parsing as HTML:

```
def with_html_parser(agent, &body)
  original_parser = agent.pluggable_parser.default
  agent.pluggable_parser.default = agent.pluggable_parser['text/html']
  begin
    yield
  ensure
    agent.pluggable_parser.default = original_parser
  end
end
```

Let me know if that does the trick.

Comment: To be totally fair, my answer isn't really saying anything that @zhon and gogogopenny haven't already said -- I'm just stating it in simpler terms.

Comment: It's a html page. The problem is the moron who wrote it didnt state that in the header. Can I force Mechanize to interpret it as a HTML file?

Answer (score 3):

When a website doesn't returns the Content Type as part of the response, you can set the Content Type yourself in a post connection hook:

```
agent = Mechanize.new { |a|
  a.post_connect_hooks << lambda { |_,_,response,_|
    if response.content_type.nil? || response.content_type.empty?
      response.content_type = 'text/html'
    end
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Small amendment:`response.content_type` may be nil, so you need to test for that, e.g. using `blank?`.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW "".blank? is part of rails not ruby.

Comment: What?  You can run ruby without rails??  ;)

Comment: Yeah, weird how a library is more popular than the language it is written in.

Answer (score -1):

have a look out for the Content-Type of the specific url in the HTTP-Headers with curl (curl yoururl -i). In your code you might want to check the content-type before you get the url:

```
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse('http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/bgb/gesamt.pdf')
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.head(url.path)}
puts res['content-type']

#=> application/pdf
```

Or you can just check if your Mechanize object is of class `Mechanize::Page`:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
unknown_body = agent.get(url)
if unknown_body.class == Mechanize::Page
  self.body = unknown_body
else
  puts "Discarded binary content!"
end
```

Be aware that this approach will be much slower since it "downloads" the  requested resource anyways.But it might be useful if you want to store the file for later usage.

Comment: Mechanize supports [`head`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-head) requests.

Comment: You can retrieve the Content-Type from Mechanize::File and you can install pluggable parsers as described above. There's no need to do the extra work, mechanize can do it all for you